mapping changing defect types across different products
I need a way to unify "defect types" and "defect subtypes" (these are fields in a salesforce object) over multiple products with each new product release.
I am a Q&R engineer (not a salesforce professional by any stretch) for a company that produces consumer electronics hardware and software. We use SF to track field failures. We have a database ("object," from what I understand) that our customer service agents add rows to with each complaint that comes in from a customer.  Each new case (row) receives a "defect type" and "subtype." Some simplified examples of rows in this table (with the "defect type - subtype" coming last):

unique case# - Product - power issue - PMIC failure
unique case# - Product - LCD issue - broken glass
unique case# - Product - FW issue - freeze during update

Each product launches with menu of a few hundred of "defect types" and "subtypes" that our customer service agents can select from when a customer calls in with a complaint. They often change slightly from one product to the next, with the newest product always being the official, POR list. For example, let's say we learned that the "freeze during update" subtype above is actually a "freeze after update" and we change the defect subtype for Product 2 to reflect that. I now have Product 1 complaints labeled differently as Product 2 complaints for the same issue.
My current approach to creating reporting that unifies these across products is to do SF exports from the database and combine them with a master Excel aligner sheet i update manually. It has a row for every product / defect type / defect subtype, and a lot of dynamically linked cells looking up the chain to the newest product. Product1 defect types points to Product2, which points to Product3, all the way to the newest product. It's several 1000's of lines and fragile as you could imagine. One accidental drag and drop, and everything explodes (and not always in the obvious all-#REFS way, sometimes everything is just off by 1 which is hard to catch visually, but ruins everything nevertheless).
Is there a way in Salesforce to add pointers, bulk over-write fields, or do something that solves this problem in a better way than how I'm doing this? Even if it's some other external approach like what I'm doing now, but not so fraught with peril, I'm open to ideas and suggestions. Thanks.
